# Alternative to erase in vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I want to use each element only once and don't want to repeat it. Consider below example:

```
v = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If I choose 2 at index 1. I don't want the program to use it again. What can I do instead of erasing it from the vector?

One part of my program is below, which I want to replace with something that is faster than `vector.erase()` (which works in `O(n)`):

```cpp
if (sz && h[k] <= t[i]) {
    cout << h[k] << '\n';
    h.erase(h.begin() + k);
}
else {
    cout << "-1\n";
}
```

Comment: Consider using stack or queue instead of vector(array). Because they are designed for one time usage of an element

Comment: `h.erase(std::unique(h.begin(), h.end()), h.end());`. The End.

Comment: A vector is probably not right data structure for the job. If you want to guarantee uniqueness, maybe a `std::set` would suit you better. If quick discarding is actually necessary, then maybe a stack or queue. I'm not reading an actual need for discarding values, just for uniqueness and single use. A set guarantees uniqueness, and just iterate the thing one time for single use and let the set go out of scope and destroy all of its contents at once.

Comment: Set it to zero or some other sentinel value that's not valid in your application?

Comment: When you said, "don't want program to use it again" do you want all instances of the value 2 to never be used again? Meaning you do not wish to use the value 2 at index 2 in addition to the value 2 at index 1?

Comment: *'If i choose 2 at index 1'* -- Do you only want to remove additional 2s, or do you also want to remove other elements that have duplicates? Is this a one time use, or should they be removed permanently? Are the data always sorted as shown in example? Does it matter which 2 we are removing from the list? Also `if(h[k] <= t[i])`, how is that related to the question?